# combobox with different worksheets, that changes worksheets in code

Tags: vba, excel

i've a question:
I would like to have a Combobox where all the worksheets are displayed. If you select a worksheet, then the worksheets in the code needs to change to the worksheet that you selected. I've tried but can't program this. 
easy example:

```
dim WRKsheet as worksheet
set worksheet = Combobox1.value
sheets(WRKsheet).activate
```

Do any of you guys know how i can succeed in this?
Grts

Comment: is it in a `User_Form` ?

Comment: yes the combobox is in a userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in a `User_Form` Module

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

' select the worksheet selected in the ComboBox1
Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Activate

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim Sht As Worksheet

' show all sheets names in thisworkbook in ComboBox1
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ComboBox1.AddItem Sht.Name
Next Sht

End Sub
```

Note: (you need to call the form from another module, with `UserForm1.Show`)

Comment: strange, i've tried with that code first but it dind't work. Now it works. Thanks